# Problem booting after installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, wubi

For the longest time I wanted to switch to Linux, and after some research, Ubuntu seemed the best bet. The last straw was when I bought an Asus X75A-DS51 Notebook, even after the free upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1, I still could not stand it. Here are the laptop's specifications: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834231037

After using an Ubuntu 13.10 install disk and installing it on separate partitions than my Windows 8.1 partitions, I get no boot menu when I start my laptop. I can only use it by putting the disc back in and running the live version. So I ran Boot-Repair and got this:

> EFI detected. Please check the options.
>
> The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after
>   changing it to EFI mode. Do you want to continue?

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda11" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda11" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda11" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common shim-signed linux-signed*

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda11" apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-efi linux
```

> Boot successfully repaired.
>
> Please write on a paper the following URL:
>   paste.ubuntu.com/6918513/
>
> In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
>   boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.
>
> You can now reboot your computer. Please do not forget to make your
>   BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!

A broken Wubi has been detected. (Note: I did not use Wubi.)

---

** EDIT **

This is the error screen I am now getting when I try to boot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6ibqu4p7dofuce/100_8497.JPG

Comment: That dropbox link doesn't work. Boot repair does very little for Wubi installs, and it's not clear from your description that you have a Wubi install (seems unlikely, otherwise Windows would be booting). If you have a computer with Windows 8 preinstalled Wubi wouldn't work anyway (UEFI/GPT disks). TL;DR update your bootrepair link.

Comment: That screen reveals that you aren't even booting using the USB, try using the USB too boot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that you basically wanna get your system working, even if it's first into windows.
If that's the case, you can simply over-write your MBR with the standard windows MBR, boot into windows, use something like easybcd to create a linux boot record in it, and use it that way.

Here's how:

Boot your linux live cd

sudo apt-get install lilo

sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr

Now boot into windows, and try fixing the MBR using easybcd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode (you have to boot the Ubuntu DVD/USB in EFI mode). You didn't because Grub2 is in the drive MBR and there are no /EFI/Ubuntu files on the EFI partition.

There is no sign of your linux boot files. They are supposed to be on /dev/sda6 according to the grub.cfg that is there.

There are in fact some Wubi remnants as well, but these do nothing other than confuse Boot repair. Boot repair is in fact flailing about because it's trying to "repair" what looks like your Ubuntu USB, fscking it and reinstalling the drive MBR.

Did you change your boot options? It should be booting in EFI mode, not BIOS mode. That photo shows that it's not detecting anything bootable on your drive. Which might explain why Windows won't boot either. So I'd recommend trying to fix that first. Once Windows is booting again, clean up those Ubuntu partitions and try to reinstall Ubuntu, this time in EFI mode. Refer to this: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/14916)